# Conditional constraint for binary

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, constraint-programming, binary-variable, logical-constraints

Could you please check where I might be wrong?
Task is:
If $z=1$, then either $x=1$ or $y=1$

My approach:
If $z=1$, then $x+y=1$
$\implies x+y\le1$
$\implies x+y\ge1$

If $z=0$, then $x+y\ge0 - M\cdot(1-z)$
$\implies x+y\ge-1 + z$

Comment: If $X$ and/or $Y$ can be equal to 1 if and only if $Z=1$, so $MZ \geq X+Y$.

If $X$ or $Y$ can be equal to 1 (but only one of them, not both) if and only if $Z=1$, so $Z \geq X+Y$.

If $X$ or $Y$ must be equal to 1 (but only one of them, not both) if and only if $Z=1$, so $Z = X+Y$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all of the variables are binary, then the logical expression is equivalent to the:

$$ z=1 \rightarrow (x=1 \lor y=1)$$
$$ (1-z) \lor (x \lor y)$$
$$ (1-z) + x + y \geq 1$$
$$ x + y -z \geq 0$$

Comment: +1 for conjunctive normal form

Comment: Thank you so much, Rob. Your insight is actually very helpful.

Comment: CNF/Logical transforms-learned in my discrete math courses both undergrad and grad, ages ago. Now trying to re-learn, thanks Rob